# Array list is not being sorted properly when it contains string

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to sort a lists of alphanumeric values , in other words a list that contains numbers and strings

Example : BOB10, BOT20, ETC...

```
List<Object> myList = _items.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ToList();
_items= new List<Object>(myList);
```

But still the output is : BOT20 , BOB10

what is wrong?

Comment: What type is `_items`?  Is `myList` really a list of `Object` or are you using "Object" as a replacement for what type it actually is in your code?

Comment: Why `List<Object>` and not `List<myType>`? If you want to sort in the specific way, you need to provide comparer. `BOB10, BOT20` - bad example, they sort fine by default. We need to know what is in your `first name`. Most likely you have some Unicode chars that skew the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : 
Try the alphanumeric algorithm approach , 
First implement the algorithm in a new class, than do this :

```
List<Object> yourList = new List < Object >(thePreviousList.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName, new AlphanumComparatorFast()).ToList())
```

As it was explained here :

http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

Implement the algorithm **AlphanumComparatorFast** by creating a new class , than just call it

Edited :

The alpha algo below :

```
Public class AlphanumComparatorFast : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        string s1 = x as string;
        if (s1 == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        string s2 = y as string;
        if (s2 == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int len1 = s1.Length;
        int len2 = s2.Length;
        int marker1 = 0;
        int marker2 = 0;

        // Walk through two the strings with two markers.
        while (marker1 < len1 && marker2 < len2)
        {
            char ch1 = s1[marker1];
            char ch2 = s2[marker2];

            // Some buffers we can build up characters in for each chunk.
            char[] space1 = new char[len1];
            int loc1 = 0;
            char[] space2 = new char[len2];
            int loc2 = 0;

            // Walk through all following characters that are digits or
            // characters in BOTH strings starting at the appropriate marker.
            // Collect char arrays.
            do
            {
                space1[loc1++] = ch1;
                marker1++;

                if (marker1 < len1)
                {
                    ch1 = s1[marker1];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (char.IsDigit(ch1) == char.IsDigit(space1[0]));

            do
            {
                space2[loc2++] = ch2;
                marker2++;

                if (marker2 < len2)
                {
                    ch2 = s2[marker2];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (char.IsDigit(ch2) == char.IsDigit(space2[0]));

            // If we have collected numbers, compare them numerically.
            // Otherwise, if we have strings, compare them alphabetically.
            string str1 = new string(space1);
            string str2 = new string(space2);

            int result;

            if (char.IsDigit(space1[0]) && char.IsDigit(space2[0]))
            {
                int thisNumericChunk = int.Parse(str1);
                int thatNumericChunk = int.Parse(str2);
                result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk);
            }
            else
            {
                result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
            }

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI @napi15, `OrderBy()` by default will sort this the way OP wants.  See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOE2Ym).  The OP did not provide enough information to diagnose the problem, but it is not likely related to how OrderBy works

Answer (score 0):

Why not use List.Sort() instead of OrderBy?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test {
    static class Program {
        static void Main() {
            List<string> list = new List<string>() {"BOT20", "BOB10", "BUG40", "BAG90"};
            list.Sort();
            foreach(var el in list)  {
                Console.Write(el + ">");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs: `BAG90>BOB10>BOT20>BUG40>`

Comment: Because OP sorts some custom type, and  we don't know if `_items` is a `List`. It is `IEnumerable` - yes. List? - we don't know

Comment: Then why just not convert it to list and then List.Sort() since he anyway converts it to List at the first line.

Comment: convert to list is extra processor usage. If `_items` is just some IEnumerable (not actual list, a query, may be), by doing bunch of linq without converting to list, you just collect operations for differed execution, without operating actual data.

Comment: Is just processing(linq'ing) IEnumerable really faster than converting to list?

Comment: Point here is that if `_items` is just an expression that derives from DB for example. when you call `ToList` it will execute "Select ... From...". If you do `sorted = _items.OrderBy`, you don't execute anything. then, you do `foreach (var item in sorted)` only then it executes actual query (or linq to objects) operation